# Is there a way to delete a large file that has already been sent to git by mistake?

Tags: git, github

I have been working on a project for some time
Some time ago, I committed a large file by mistake and then pushed it
Now, every time I want to push the changes, that large file must also be pushed, which is about 200 MB, even though I deleted the file from the project.

Note that I cannot go back to previous commits
Now is there a way to stop pushing the large file?
Or
Without resetting the repository (I need repository history), can I send only the files that are currently in the project to Git, just like when we create a repository for the first time?